# always true rewritecond

Tags: apache-http-server

My university provides a `public_html` file in each student's Linux directory so tat each student can have a webpage.  I want to put all my PHP scripts into that file and place the index in a sub-directory called `webroot`.  I'm trying to work out a way to have an `.htaccess` file in the `public_html` that will redirect ALL requests in that folder to be redirected.

There's lots of advice on redirecting any file that doesn't exists but I want to redirect regardless of the existence of a file.  Can I use something like `RewriteCond TRUE`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need a `RewriteCond`, If you just have a `RewriteRule` it will always be executed.

[Mod_Rewrite is extensively well documented](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), please *read the friendly manual*.

Comment: I've been looking through that document for a while now.  /Extensive/ documentation is not always friendly for the beginner.

Comment: @Matt: This is a reference documentation, it needs to be complex because the topic is complex. Google is your friend for beginner tutorials.

Comment: @Matt While the documentation might not spoon feed it to you, as a IT Professional you are expected to be able to read and comprehend extensive and well documented systems. If you're not that kind of professional, [SF] isn't for you (per our [FAQ]).

Comment: My mistake then.  Just seemed out of place at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch permanent ^~username/$ http://example.com/~username/php/index.php
```

That should redirect any request for the root to your index file (not tested). Adjust to match your public_html url and domain.